# Vue-Axios errors do not propagate to catch async try catch block

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am using Axios to post to an api from within the Vuex store and when the api gets an error back from the sever, it throws an error, which fails to be caught in a try catch block.

// the action

```
async register({ commit }, params) {
    // I use an axios interceptor to format all responses like this 
    // so I can avoid having to use try-catch at least when using axios.
    const [res, { error }] = await Vue.axios.post(`${params.type}`, params);
    if (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
```

// In the component

```
try {
  const response = await this.$store.dispatch('handleAuthEvent', payload);
  // do stuff with response
} catch (error) {
  // `error` here is not defined, even though I passed it in the `throw` from the backend
  this.showError();
}
```

// main.js

```
import axios from './axiosConfig.js'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
```

// axiosConfig.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

const API_URL = process.env.API_URL || 'http://localhost:3030/'

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token
  }
})

// format response data to avoid having to use try/catch blocks with async/await
instance.interceptors.response.use(data => {
  return [data, null];
}, error => {
  return [null, error.response.data.error || "server error"];
});

export default instance;
```

Comment: Can you show how do you import the package `axios`?

Comment: @RuChernChong Added above. I use `vue-axios` so I can access `axios` on any vue component without needing to explicitly import it in each file.

Comment: Try using `window.axios = axios` and you can use `window.axios.create()` globally. I cannot determine which part when wrong. We need to narrow it down first.